# Finding a Table's Contents in Another Table using BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have two tables, table A and table B:

A has data stored in this way:

```
word1
word4
word2
word3
```

B has data stored in this way:

```
  word1            value1
  word1            value2
  word2            value3 
  word2            value4
  word2            value5 
  word3            value6
  word3            value7
```

what is the query I can use in google BigQuery to generate a table such as

```
word1    value1+value2
word2    value3+value4+value5
word3    value6+value7
```

where word1, word2, etc are Strings, and value1, value2, etc are integers?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you don't need to use table A for this problem at all, because the words also exist in table B. And then it becomes straight aggregation query

```
SELECT word, SUM(value) FROM B GROUP BY value
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want only the words exist in both the tables, use a JOIN CLAUSE.

Example:
SELECT T1.word as word,value FROM (
SELECT word,sum(value) as value FROM B GROUP BY word) AS T1 JOIN (
SELECT word FROM A GROUP BY word) AS T2 ON T1.word=T2.word